# Finding the current flowing through diode with knee voltage of 0.6 V and internal resistance of 200 Ω

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes

I am trying to find the current flowing across this diode as it assumes different models.
[image]

I have calculated the current assuming the diode is ideal, as well as assuming it had a knee voltage of 0.6 V. However, I am stuck on the case where the diode also has an internal resistance (in this case 200 Ω). My book tells me I can replace this diode with the following design:

[image]

But I have not been able to find this anywhere else. Does this mean I can simplify the circuit by combining the voltage sources and resistors to find the current?

Comment: Your voltage source is ambiguous; in the UK, the positive terminal would be seen as the node closest to the arrowhead yet, in parts of Europe, the arrow will represent the electric field line direction and imply an opposite polarity to the UK.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the better model, we can combine the two resistors into one, and the two voltage sources into one.

But watch out the polarity of the 5V voltage source: **with the conventions I have been taught**, the diode is reverse-biased, so the knee voltage of 0.6V is irrelevant (the current is extremely small, like nanoamps, and temperature-dependent). I just realize that the convention taught for voltage changes according to location! In France, the voltage and current arrows are in the same directions for a generator, in opposite directions for a receiver, thus the question's schematic would be for a reverse-biased diode, see e.g. [this](http://users.polytech.unice.fr/%7Ecpeter/ELEC/DOCS_COURS/3_diodes.pdf#page=2) or [this](http://sen.champo.free.fr/coursenligne/La%20diode.php) or [this](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode#/media/Fichier:Diode_symbole.png). But that's apparently reversed in some countries, see e.g. [this](https://www.electronicsplanet.ch/en/electronics/diode-and-resistor-in-series/diode-and-resistor-in-series.php).

Comment: in that case wouldn’t the current always be 0 no matter the model? Sorry I am new to this but from the way it is defined in my book this looks to be a forward-biased diode unless the voltage source is negative or the diode is pointing in the opposite direction.

Comment: @user1171376: looks like the convention regarding arrows on voltage sources that I and my two child are taught in France is not the same as the one in some other parts of the world. See added text.

Comment: I see now, sorry for the confusion. You are right the convention is different in many European countries as well and this is basically the same as the one in the US(but using an arrow insead of (+-).